# Solving a 2nd order non linear ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any method prescribed to find the general solution of the following ODE analytically?

$$
3y_{xx}^{2} + xy_{x}+y=0
$$

If that square term would not have been present in $y_{xx}$ then it was quite easy to solve but I am totally blank with this one. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably not a full general solution, but this problem does appear to admit asymptotic beavior proportional to $1/x$ as $x\to\infty$. Do you have boundary conditions to pin this down?

Comment: I thought boundary conditions wouldn't be of much help in generalizing this equation. But since you have asked, $y_{x} (0)=0$ and when $x \rightarrow \infty $, $y=0$

Comment: Use series expansion

Comment: You can automatize the equation via the transformation $y=x^4u$, $x=e^t$, and then you can reduce it to a first order ODE via the transformation $u'=p(u)$. Looks pretty bad after that.